# Oracle DDL Python Scripting

Tags: python, oracle, scripting, ddl

I have a Oracle database, that contains metadata of Database Tables. Example.

Table- Entity
Entity Property
Emp Table
Position Table

Table Attributes
Attributes     Table_Name
Emp_Name       Emp
Emp_No         Emp
Emp_Add        Emp
Postion_id     Position
Position_Name  Position

I want a python script which you create DDL for the above tables. 
For example, the output should contain like this tables
create table 'emp','details'
create table 'position','details'

For Attributes, I would like the script to output like this
put   'emp','1','details:Emp_Name','1'
put 'emp','1','details:Emp_No','1'

Please, advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should pay attention on DBMS_METADATA package.

For example:

```
select DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE', 'EMP') from dual;
```

link on [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm#BGBBIEGA).
It is available for all Oracle users.

Comment: We are building the table structure from the entries from another table.  The DBMS_METADATA will not work in this case.